# How to install fan drivers for ASUS FX504 laptop on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, asus, fan

I have ASUS FX504GD having ubuntu 18.04.1 and kernel 4.20 .

For some reason I am not able to find fan drivers for ubuntu.
This laptop has a dual fan.

I tried installing **asus_fan** from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fan_speed_control#Asus_laptops but having no luck since this module works only for the older Asus laptops.

This is the output I get after running **sensors** command

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:       -1 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +55.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```